# is it possible to link a field to a property of a control in formregions

Tags: forms, outlook

I am developing an add-in for outlook 2013/2016.
Thus far I've been using vbscript for my forms.
However, needing not to have code exposed to anyone 
who knows how to hit'design this form' and for easier 
upgrading I was considering to switch to formregions.

My problem is how to assign the properties of a control
created in c# form region in the way that is done in outlook forms
(that are meant to contain form regions)

But I cannot find any help and references for that purpose
Does anyone know of a workaround?or some documentation, maybe?

PS:Importing the form region results in error:
'The installation Path for outlook 15 cannot be determined'
(I am running vsto 15 in office 16 64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

thnx for all the effort!!!
the conversation got quite long
and i am gratefull.
i have taken your answers into 
account but i could not complete
the puzzle starting from all
of the points you made.

Instead i will answer this question
with a complete tutorial i found.

Actually it dates back to office 2007
(so i avoided it initially because,
you know, technologies change
but i tried on 2016 and verified it works!!!
the link is at :
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1327185

Comment: The link is very informative compared to others. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can persist any property on an item using `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty/SetProperty` or the `UserProperties` collection.

Comment: and do you have to create a form (.oft) that includes form regions(.ofs)? - so that you are able to create userproperties in outlook(.oft)?

Comment: No, your code and your controls in your form region are free to read and set any properties on the underlying Outlook item.

Comment: don't you need to add userproperties to the appointment so that it stores(or should I say design-in) fields for every appointment.I mean adding properties must be something done once and await for data/content.Any directions?

Comment: You are the one who decides when and how the properties are added - it is your code.

Comment: from your welcoming contribution i'd like to ask how to add a userproperty. I mean accessor is for getting and setting and indeed very helpful but how do you expand the standard properties(i'd say once on install or first ribbon_load) and add new property that is fed with content on every new instance(of any appointment(or other IPM.)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - doesn't your form region already process the item being displayed? Do you not access any of its properties? Or are you asking how a ribbon button can set a property from its click event?

Comment: I think these are three different things and possible translations to my problem. Let's start backwards. I know clicking events are accessible from the form region designed in visual studio. Clear-I've tested it. Back to first :i think I can access known properties. read it, not yet tested.

Comment: Finally the second choice seems closer to what I ask: I reckon there is a procedure for defining fields/user properties that is separate from accessing them{get;set;}. I want to create them once, if possible, and fill them(optionally or required) in on any\every  create_appointment_event. I've been successfully using them with .oft where they appear in (All fields). but how do you merge them with form regions...That is the question

Comment: Your form region is free to set any properties when it is first displayed or at any later point. I would not do that if I were you - you will "dirty" the item for no good reason and the user will be prompted to save the item even if no changes have been done by the user. Your code that populates the values in thee controls would have to deal with missing properties and use some default values. When the item is being saved, you can save the values from the controls to the item itself

Comment: I think I get it now!!!can you provide a couple of lines on how to save values to the item itself?

Comment: MailItem.UserProperties.Add would do the job.

Comment: plus there is another twist. I need to assign a form as an extension of a specific calendar and not on others

Comment: Then you should not use a form region (which is message class based), but rather a task pane (which you instantiate explicitly - or not - for each item).

Comment: thnx Dmitry, I appreciate all the help

Comment: and did it! with a little bit of extra search I fitted the pieces together! thnx a lot and mark this question(s) as answered

Comment: @Kefalas Savvas - I cannot mark a reply as an answer, only you (the original poster) can.